# Getting an error "Missing image file in request. (Perhaps ...)" while generating image variations using openai and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, http, xmlhttprequest, openai-api

I am getting above mentioned error. I think error is due the fact that I am sending ImageData. Even in the documenation, it is written that you can send ImageData but that example is specifically for node.js and is using a openai library openai.createImageVariation(). Whereas I am using JavaScript and directly sending http request using endpoint. You can look of "Using in-memory image data
" an example here.

https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/images/language-specific-tips?context=node&lang=node.js

I think the issue can be solved if I can convert ImageData into a .png file and then send it. However, I do not know how to do it. Somebody mentioned that you can convert image into b64 or blob, however that is for the 'img' and I have ImageData as I am preprocessing the image.

This is my code.

```
//Function for sending http request
async function generateVariation(formData) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("https://api.openai.com/v1/images/variations", {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData,
      headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer" + " " + api_key}
    });
    const result = await response.json();
    console.log("Success:", result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
  }
}
  
  // Calling it. Here I am using image data. I am sending the image but still it says 
  //that image is required

  const form_data = new FormData();
  form_data.append("image",imageData);
  form_data.append("n",1);
  form_data.append("size",'1024x1024');

  generateVariation(form_data);
```

Any help? Thanks